# Trying to delete 2 rows in database using JPA. One object is created from id but other isnt

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm trying to delete the 2 rows(1 in each table) with the same id, in my service class, the breweries object is being created with the id fine but when the BreweriesGeocode object is trying to be created the BreweriesGeocode object brakes out of the try and brings me to my error.jsp page.

The line of code that causes it to break is

```
   bg = em.createNamedQuery("BreweriesGeocode.findById", BreweriesGeocode.class)
            .setParameter("id", (id))
            .getSingleResult();
```

the code for the entire method of deleteAnBrewery in BreweriesService.java is

```
public void deleteAnBrewery(int id) {
    EntityManager em = DBUtil.getEMF().createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction trans = em.getTransaction();
    Breweries b = null;
    BreweriesGeocode bg = null;
    try {                                                                                            
        b = em.createNamedQuery("Breweries.findById", Breweries.class)
                .setParameter("id", (id))
                .getSingleResult();
        bg = em.createNamedQuery("BreweriesGeocode.findById", BreweriesGeocode.class)
                .setParameter("id", (id))
                .getSingleResult();
        trans.begin();
        em.remove(em.merge(b));
        em.remove(em.merge(bg));
        trans.commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error in getting property details: " + ex);
    } finally {
        em.clear();
        em.close();
    }

}
```

I am not getting any error in the terminal

Comment: It's hard to say what happens without the exact error. Try to remove the `catch (Exception ex)` block and see if the stacktrace is logged in the console then.

Comment: @SergeiPetunin I've given that a try but it still gives no errors, thanks for the advice tho

Comment: To get error logs try to change `System.out.println("Error in getting property details: " + ex);` to `throw new RuntimeException("Error in getting property details: ", ex);`

Comment: You can get errors because of a foreign key between the tables. In this case you might use cascade delete, which could remove child records automatically. To use cascade delete you need to update your DB.

Comment: Or just remove child record first (in your case it's BreweriesGeocode, as I understand).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't set the objects to null outside the `try`, I don't know if that was the fix because I wouldn't think that would make a difference, the only other change was turning my Netbeans off and on again, this is not a reliable solution

```
public void deleteAnBrewery(int id) {
EntityManager em = DBUtil.getEMF().createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction trans = em.getTransaction();


try {                                                                                            
   Breweries b = em.createNamedQuery("Breweries.findById", Breweries.class)
            .setParameter("id", (id))
            .getSingleResult();
   BreweriesGeocode  bg = em.createNamedQuery("BreweriesGeocode.findById", BreweriesGeocode.class)
            .setParameter("id", (id))
            .getSingleResult();
    trans.begin();
    em.remove(em.merge(b));
    em.remove(em.merge(bg));
    trans.commit();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Error in getting property details: " + ex);
} finally {
    em.clear();
    em.close();
}
```

}